# .hgignore - ignore some folders except one specific folder

Tags: mercurial

__

Hello everybody,

My hgignore file contains following lines:

```
syntax:regexp
^data/dyn/.*
^data/config/.*
^data/temp/.*
^data/mediapool
^\.project
^\.buildpath
^\.settings/.*
^nbproject/.*
/\.git/
\.hg_archival.txt
syntax:glob
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
sftp-config.json
```

BUT, i want to "unignore" the folder data/dyn/xxx/yyy with it's files inside.

How can i solve my problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mercurial `.hgignore` files are a blacklist only.  The only way to whitelist something is to blacklist the "outer" group and then `hg add` what you want not-ignore.  Adding something with `hg add` always trumps ignoring it in `.hgignore`.

That works great for files, but not so great for directories since you can't add directories.  You can add all the files in them, but any new files that land there will be ignored until you add them.

You can try using the "[zero-length negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)" feature of regular expressions, but honestly it's easier to just add the files in that directory.